# Почему и как срабатывает команда from app import app?

Tags: python, python-import

Имеется простая пакетная структура:

```
└── myproject
    |
    ├── app
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── views.py
    |
    └── run.py
```

__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

run.py:

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

Почему в данном случае **объект** app класса flask номально импортируется из **пакета** app, хотя и не является модулем? При попытке определить объект app, например, в views.py, он уже не импортируется.

Answer (score 3):

Почему не импортируется? Все прекрасно импортируется :).
Когда ты объявляешь классы/функции/объекты в `__init__.py` ты объявляешь их на уровне модуля. И в импорте ты пишешь просто имя модуля: `from module import obj`. Точно так же можно сделать объявление в подмодуле, но тогда и в импорте надо указывать имя подмодуля: `from module.submodule import obj`. В твоем случае `from app.view import app`.

Answer (score 3):

[Импорт в Питоне объединяет две операции](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

1. найти (загрузить  и проинициализировать) модуль
2. ввести новые имена в текущем окружении  (как операция присваивания `=`)

> Почему и как срабатывает команда from app import app?

`from module import name` импортирует `module` модуль и если он не содержит `name` имя, то происходит попытка импортировать `module.name` модуль. Если `name` уже существует, то `name` модуль не импортируется, а просто аналог `name = module.name` исполняется.

В коде, представленном в вопросе, `app` имя уже существует в `app` модуле поэтому просто импортируется модуль `app` и в текущем пространстве имён новое имя создаётся (аналог: `app = __import__('app').app`).

> Почему в данном случае объект app класса flask нормально импортируется из пакета app, хотя и не является модулем?

Все имена, присвоенные в `app/__init__.py`, доступны как `app.имя` после импорта `app` пакета (`import app`).

`app.app` уже доступен, поэтому не происходит попытки импортировать `app.app` модуль. Если удалить `app = ...` из `__init__.py`, то произойдёт попытка импорта `app.app` модуля.

[Рекомендуется `app = Flask(__name__)` внутрь функции `create_app(...)` помещать](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/20/), чтобы можно было разные параметры передавать (например, для тестов).

> При попытке определить объект app, например, в views.py, он уже не импортируется.

Вложенные модули неявно не импортируются (`from app import app`) не импортирует `views.py` модуль. Если `views.py` содержит `name = 'value'`, то чтобы импортировать `name` имя в `run.py` следует написать:

```
from app.views import name
```

Если есть желание углубиться, то [все детали системы импорта описаны в спецификации Питона](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).