# Замена urllib в pythone 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.5

Помогите пожалуйста с этим кодом:

```
key = "key"
secret = "secret"

nonce = 13

params = {"method":"getInfo", "nonce": nonce}
params = urllib.urlencode(params)

H = hmac.new(secret, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
H.update(params)
sign = H.hexdigest()
```

`urllib` в 3 ветке изменен, я не могу разобратся

Comment: Во-первых, используйте возможности разметки, как-то выделение кода специальным образом. Во-вторых, неясно, что у вас за проблема, возможно есть другие, более корректные способы её решения, т.о. опишите детально какие ошибки возникают и при каких условиях.

Comment: я только учусь, но в общем такая ошибка: params =   urllib.urlencode(params)
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlencode' то есть urllib не устанавливается,а на сайте написано что он изменен на urllib.requests

Comment: @владимиржалеев `from urllib.parse import urlencode`

Comment: NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined вот как то так  да и документации ничего вообще ясного и понятного нету

Comment: @владимиржалеев вы шутите? После такого импорта нужно писать `params = urlencode(params)` а не `params = urllib.urlencode(params)`

Comment: @владимиржалеев: то что  `from module import function` не делает имя `module` доступным в Питоне это достаточно базовая вещь. Вам стоит [любую книгу по Питону](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420125/23044) прочитать, чтобы сэкономить время и на пустяках не спотыкаться. Вот посмотрите кратко [Почему и как срабатывает команда `from app import app`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488152/23044)