# Методы импорта и их преимущества

Tags: python, импорт

Насколько я понял, в python есть 3 метода импорта

1.`from 'имя_модуля' import 'имя_класса'`

2.`import 'имя_модуля'`

3.`from 'имя_модуля' import *`

Если использовать 2 способ, то обращаться к классам придётся:

`'имя_модуля'.'имя_класса'`

Во всех остальных способах обращение без точки, так словно этот класс уже в нашем модуле. Но почему-то не рекомендуют использовать 3 способ, объясняя это тем, что возникает возможность конфликта имен между имен класса импортируемого модуля и модуля, в котором мы находимся.

1. Почему же такого не происходит, когда мы импортируем 2-ым способом. Ведь там и там происходит импорт всего файла и создания тех же переменных в нашем пространстве имен(namespace) или нет?
2. Что и в каком случае лучше использовать?

Comment: похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487660/23044

Comment: а еще есть importlib

Comment: В первых двух случаях вы точно знаете, что в вашем пространстве имён появятся только `имя_модуля` или `имя_класса`, а вот в третьем случае хрен знает что появится, пока не заглянуть в содержимое импортируемого модуля (а постоянно заглядывать туда не очень удобно, знаете ли)

Comment: старайтесь одной проблемой на вопрос ограничиваться (более специфичный вопрос повышает сигнал/шум соотношение -- более полезен для будущих посетителей из гугла).  К примеру, «почему `from модуль import *` не следует кроме особых случаев использовать» можно отдельно спросить.

Comment: `from модуль import * ` обычно используют, когда в модуле такая туча классов и констант, что код начинает слишком "раздуваться". Типичные случаи - `tkinter, tkinter.ttk, ctypes` при этом, естетсвенно, бывают конфликты имен... которые я, например, уже ловил, и понять, в чем дело, бывает достаточно трудно....